# Using 64-bit python on visual studio with pybind11

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to write c++ code to interact with my python application, I'm using a 64-bit interpreter, a 64-bit version of pybind11 and I'm compiling the code to a 64-bit `.pyd`. This is my code so far:

```
#include <pybind11-global/pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cmath>

namespace py = pybind11;

const double e = 2.7182818284590452353602874713527;

double sinh_impl(double x) {
    return (1 - pow(e, (-2 * x))) / (2 * pow(e, -x));
}

double cosh_impl(double x) {
    return (1 + pow(e, (-2 * x))) / (2 * pow(e, -x));
}

double tanh_impl(double x) {
    return sinh_impl(x) / cosh_impl(x);
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(gtpec_cluster, m) {
    m.def("fast_tanh2", &tanh_impl, R"pbdoc(
        Compute a hyperbolic tangent of a single argument expressed in radians.
    )pbdoc");

#ifdef VERSION_INFO
    m.attr("__version__") = VERSION_INFO;
#else
    m.attr("__version__") = "dev";
#endif
}
```

When I build the solution I am able to import it from a python code:

```
>>> from gtpec_cluster import fast_tanh2
>>> fast_tanh2(2)
0.9640275800758167
>>>
```

But if I'm running from within visual studio it gives me the error that `gtpec_cluster.pyd is not a valid Win32 application`. Is there a way of telling Visual Studio that it should be using 64-bit instead of a 32-bit library? This is the python that I'm using:

[image]

Comment: The name "Win32" doesn't mean it's a 32-bit application. What exactly are you running from within Visual Studio?

Comment: I just clicked the "Local Windows Debugger" from Visual Studio, the code is the same as I typed in the interpreter, and I've added the C++ project as a reference from my python project

Comment: The Python module is a DLL, not an application. You cannot run a DLL. Maybe you need [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/debugging-mixed-mode-c-cpp-python-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)?

Comment: Yes, but I selected the python project before clicking on "Local Windows Debugger" I want to run the python code, not the DLL

Comment: I don't know what exactly the problem is, but I'm pretty sure you need to share a some more logs and/or possibly screenshots. Perhaps even better, create a [mcve] and put it on github (the preference is to post it directly here, but this is not really possible in this case).

Comment: `pow(e, (-2 * x))` never use pow to get eˣ like this. Always use `exp(-2*x)`

Comment: actually just use `t = exp(-x); return (1 - t*t) / (2 * t);`, no need to inefficiently recalculating the powers

Comment: @phuclv The code itself is just copied from [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/working-with-c-cpp-python-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022), my code is totally unrelated, I was just worried about the project setup

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're in Visual Studio, you can then right-click on the Python project in the Solution Explorer and click "Set as Startup Project". You can then proceed to Start.